# SQL delete all consecutive records that have the same value, leaving only first and last

Tags: sql-server

i have a situation where i need to delete consecutive records that share the same field value ("Failed to notify Customer") , however i need to leave the first and last instance

sample data

```
date             type    log
20/11/2014 09:05 System, Order Added
20/11/2014 09:18 Mark,   Invoice Printed
20/11/2014 10:00 System, Failed to notify Customer
20/11/2014 10:05 System, Failed to notify Customer
20/11/2014 10:10 System, Failed to notify Customer
20/11/2014 10:15 System, Failed to notify Customer
20/11/2014 10:20 System, Failed to notify Customer
20/11/2014 12:05 System, Order Completed
```

resulting output

```
date             type    log
20/11/2014 09:05 System, Order Added
20/11/2014 09:18 Mark,   Invoice Printed
20/11/2014 10:00 System, Failed to notify Customer
20/11/2014 10:20 System, Failed to notify Customer
20/11/2014 12:05 System, Order Completed
```

Is there some way of formulating an sql server query to achieve this? for the life of me i cant get my head around how i would approach this

Comment: Forewarning: So far as I can tell all of the proposed answers on this question—including the selected answer—fail to account for the _consecutive_ part of the question. They may work for this simplified data set, but would also delete any _non-consecutive_ duplicates present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

*Sample data :*

```
use tempdb

create table temp(
    [date]  datetime,
    type    varchar(100),
    [log]   varchar(100)
)
insert into temp values
('11/20/2014 09:05', 'System', 'Order Added'),
('11/20/2014 09:18', 'Mark', 'Invoice Printed'),
('11/20/2014 10:00', 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer'),
('11/20/2014 10:05', 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer'),
('11/20/2014 10:10', 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer'),
('11/20/2014 10:15', 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer'),
('11/20/2014 10:20', 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer'),
('11/20/2014 12:05', 'System', 'Order Completed');
```

*Solution using `ROW_NUMBER()` :*

```
with cte as(
    select
        *,
        rn = row_number() over(partition by log order by [date]),
        cc = count(*) over(partition by log)
    from temp
    where
        log = 'Failed to notify Customer'
)
delete
from cte
where
    rn > 1 and rn < cc

select * from temp
drop table temp
```

Comment: That won't work if "Failed to notify Customer" comes back later in the sequence but is not consecutive to the previously entered "Failed to notify Customer"

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from table-name where  log='Failed to notify Customer' 
group by log having date>min(date) and date<max(date);
```

This will select the required rows and delete these rows.

P.S - Syntax may be wrong as I didn't execute and check.

Comment: That might work for the specific case but otherwise it would clear all middle logs if there are other kinds of logs between. 

(Order Added)
(Invoice Printed)
(Failed to notify Customer  <- stays)
(Failed to notify Customer < - is deleted)
(SomeOtherLog)
(Failed to notify Customer <- is deleted)
(Failed to notify Customer <- is deleted)
(Failed to notify Customer  <-stays)

Answer (score 1):

select table that contains the max(date) for each customer and union that with one that contains the min(date) for each customer. Then delete from table where not in your union.
Something like this (untested)

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT Max(Date), Type, Log
FROM Table
WHERE type = 'System' AND log = 'Failed to notify customer'
GROUP BY Type, Log
UNION ALL
SELECT Min(Date), Type, Log
FROM Table
WHERE type = 'System' AND log = 'Failed to notify customer'
GROUP BY Type, Log)
```

Comment: This will delete _non-consecutive_ duplicates, whereas the OP is only looking to delete _consecutive_ duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Group By and Having clause to get the log value having count more than 1 and then we can get MIN and MAX date for the same.

Check this script:

```
--Create table
Create table #test
(
date1 datetime,
type varchar(25),
log1 varchar(100)
)

--Inserting data
Set dateformat dmy
Insert into #Test values(cast('20/11/2014 09:05' as datetime), 'System', 'Order Added')
Insert into #Test values(cast('20/11/2014 09:18' as datetime), 'Mark',   'Invoice Printed')
Insert into #Test values(cast('20/11/2014 10:00' as datetime), 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer')
Insert into #Test values(cast('20/11/2014 10:05' as datetime), 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer')
Insert into #Test values(cast('20/11/2014 10:10' as datetime), 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer')
Insert into #Test values(cast('20/11/2014 10:15' as datetime), 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer')
Insert into #Test values(cast('20/11/2014 10:20' as datetime), 'System', 'Failed to notify Customer')
Insert into #Test values(cast('20/11/2014 12:05' as datetime), 'System', 'Order Completed')

--Delete operation
Delete From #test 
Where date1 <> (Select MIN(date1) from #Test where log1 = ((SELECT Log1 from #test group by log1 having COUNT(log1) > 1)))
and date1 <> (Select MAX(date1) from #Test where log1 = ((SELECT Log1 from #test group by log1 having COUNT(log1) > 1)))
and log1 = (SELECT Log1 from #test group by log1 having COUNT(log1) > 1)

--Checking output
Select * from #Test
```